# When and how to add WiFi driver when using WDS imaging

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, windows-7

I'm setting up WDS to image a set of laptops. The install is done over ethernet, which works fine. However the laptops need to connect to WiFi using the built in card. The drivers aren't installed as part of the setup. When and how is the appropriate way to introduce them? Lots of articles talk about injecting network card drivers into the boot image, but this is in order to connect to the WDS. I don't need to use the WiFi drivers to do the imaging I just need them to be installed as part of the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the official documentation on how to do this for 2003.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766141%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[Here's the official documentation on how to do this for 2008R2.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348456%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Obviously, 2008R2 is much easier ... Good luck!